# Printing object values using for loop

Tags: java, object, attributes

Suppose we have a class named Job. Job has ten objects like j1,j2,j3. Job has an attribute JOBNO.

Is it possible to print JOBNO of all the objects using for loop ? Or we have to call each object to print the JOBNO ? Thank you in advance

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: Define your object in an array, and iterate through the array.

Comment: Do you have the ten objects in a collection? List or Array?

Comment: @TDG Can't we iterate through each object in a class ? I am new to Java. Sorry if it's silly

Comment: @PeterRader No Collections. Just like j1,j2,j3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To itterate using a loop, you need a new Variable, a array, list or set.

See this new variable of type array:

```
Job[] jobs = new Job[]{j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,j6,j7,j8,j9,j10};
```

Now you can use a loop:

```
for (Job jobVariable : jobs){
    System.out.println(jobVariable.JOBNO);
}
```

This will print all ten JOBNO to the console.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to print JOBNO of all the objects using for loop ? Or we have to call each object to print the JOBNO ?

It's possible. You'll need an array (other data structures like Lists can also work) for this.

For example

```
Job[] jobs = {j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,j6,j7,j8,j9,j10};  // Created an array of Job objects and added j1,j2....j10 to it
```

Now you can use the for loop to access the JOBNO attribute of each element of jobs. Like:

```
for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  System.out.println(jobs[index].JOBNO);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumption:

I guess, your code is something like this,

```
Job j1,j2,j3;//
//j1, j2,j3 are instantiated.
```

`No` you can not do this without a collection. You have to add them to a collection before you loop through it and do what ever you like with each of the items in that collection. In this case print the JOBNO.