# How does a value in an entry in the WeakHashMap gets garbage collected when the actual object is garbage collected?

Tags: java, collections, garbage-collection, weak-references, weakhashmap

First of all I would like to clarify my understanding of the `WeakReference` as the following question depends on the same.

```
static void test() {
    Person p = new Person();
    WeakReference<Person> person = new WeakReference<>(p);
    p = null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println(person.get());
    System.out.println(person);
}

static class Person {
    String name;
}

static class PersonMetadata {
    String someData;

    public PersonMetadata(String met) {
        someData = met;
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is

`null
java.lang.ref.WeakReference@7852e922`

Which means that although there is the actual person object is garbage collected once a GC runs, there is an object of `WeakReference<Person>` class is there in the memory which does not point to anything at this point.

Now considering the above understanding true, I am confused about how does `WeakHashMap<K,V>` works. In the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.name = "John";
    WeakHashMap<Person, PersonMetadata> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
    PersonMetadata meta = new PersonMetadata("Geek");
    map.put(p, meta);
    p = null;
    System.gc();
    if (map.values().contains(meta)) {
        System.out.println("Value present");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Value gone");
    }
}

static class Person {
    String name;
}

static class PersonMetadata {
    String someData;

    public PersonMetadata(String met) {
        someData = met;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `Value gone`

Now the **the question** is as it is said that the key in `WeakHashMap<K,V>` is an weak reference which means that in the above code when **`p`** becomes `null` the actual object can be garbage collected as there is no more strong reference to the object, but **how does the and the value which is an object of `PersonMetadata` class is getting garbage collected** as the first code proves that object of `WeakReference` class is not garbage collected even though the actual object is collected.

Comment: I've explained the way to cleanup weak references answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285504/how-to-add-the-value-of-all-the-objects/32286324#32286324).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the situation. When `map.values().contains(meta)`, or short `map.containsValue(meta)` returns `false`, it doesn’t imply that `meta` has been garbage collected. In fact, you are holding a reference to the object in `meta` and even passing that reference to the `contains` method which may invoke `equals` on it. So how could that object be garbage collected?

The response only tells you that there is no association from one of the map’s keys to that object and since the only key has been garbage collected, that’s the correct answer. Alternatively, you could just have asked `map.isEmpty()` to check for the presence of the association.

This is what the [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/util/WeakHashMap.html) provides:

> Hash table based implementation of the `Map` interface, with *weak keys*. An entry in a `WeakHashMap` will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively removed from the map, so this class behaves somewhat differently from other `Map` implementations.

The removal of the entry is not instantaneous. It relies on enqueuing of the `WeakReference` into a `ReferenceQueue`, which is then polled internally when you make the next query, like `containsValue` or even `size()`. E.g. if I change your program to:

```
Person p = new Person();
WeakHashMap<Person, PersonMetadata> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
PersonMetadata meta = new PersonMetadata("Geek");
map.put(p, meta);
WeakReference<?> ref = new WeakReference<>(p);
p = null;
while(ref.get() != null) System.gc();
System.out.println(map.containsValue(meta)? "Value present": "Value gone");
```

It occasionally prints “Value present” despite the key `Person` instance provenly has been garbage collected at this point. As said above, this is about the map’s internal cleanup, not about the `PersonMetadata` instance to which we’re holding a strong reference in `meta` anyway.

Making `PersonMetadata` eligible to garbage collection is an entirely different thing. As said, the `WeakReference` does an internal cleanup whenever we call a method an it. If we don’t, there will be no cleanup and hence, still a strong reference, even if the key has been garbage collected. Consider:

```
Person p = new Person();
WeakHashMap<Person, PersonMetadata> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
PersonMetadata meta = new PersonMetadata("Geek");
map.put(p, meta);
WeakReference<?> personRef = new WeakReference<>(p);
WeakReference<?> metaRef = new WeakReference<>(meta);
p = null;
meta = null;
while(personRef.get() != null) System.gc();
System.out.println("Person collected");
for(int i = 0; metaRef.get() != null && i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("PersonMetadata not collected");
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
System.out.println("calling a query method on map");
System.out.println("map.size() == "+map.size());
System.gc();
System.out.println("PersonMetadata "+(metaRef.get()==null? "collected": "not collected"));
```

Which will print

```
Person collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
PersonMetadata not collected
calling a query method on map
map.size() == 0
PersonMetadata collected
```

demonstrating how the `WeakHashMap` holds a strong reference to the value of an already collected key until we eventually invoke a method on it, to give it a chance to perform its internal cleanup.

The value finally gets collected when neither, the `WeakHashMap` nor our method, hold a reference on it. When we remove the `meta = null;` statement, the map still will be empty at the end (after its internal cleanup), but the value won’t be collected.

It’s important to keep in mind that these code examples are for demonstration purposes and touch implementation specific behavior, most notably, that a `main` method usually runs unoptimized. Formally, local variables are not required to prevent garbage collection if the referent is otherwise unused, a point which has relevance in practice when methods have been optimized.

Comment: Thanks @Holger thanks for this valuable input, the part which has clarified my doubt is **The removal of the entry is not instantaneous. It relies on enqueuing of the WeakReference into a ReferenceQueue**. I am accepting this as the answer.

Comment: I see it is only for demonstration, but I have a couple of questions 1)Is it possible that the last `System.gc` might not result in the collection of `meta` and the last line print `not collected` (after `WeakHashMap` internal clean up) (since we are not looping till `metaRef.get()==null` and I *feel* that we are just giving it one chance).  2) *Theoretically* can `while(personRef.get() != null) System.gc();` result in an infinite loop?

Comment: @user7 yes, that’s for demonstration only and assuming a JVM like HotSpot in its default configuration where `System.gc()` is respected and sufficient for cleaning the reference.  In other environments, the last line could print “not collected” and `while(personRef.get() != null) System.gc();` could loop forever. In these environments, the example code wouldn’t be sufficient to demonstrate the workings of `WeakHashMap`. In fact, it would be impossible to create any code for demonstrating its behavior for such environments.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @Holger there is a tiny question that I have for the first snippet, how come I sometimes see `Value Present`? Does that mean the publishing to that `ReferenceQueue` is not instant? because internally once `containsValue` is called, `expungeStaleEntries` is called also...

Comment: @Eugene yes, publishing to the `ReferenceQueue` is not instantaneous, at least not on HotSpot/OpenJDK. The garbage collector will hand over the discovered references to another thread which will eventually enqueue the references. [The magic starts here](https://searchcode.com/file/123104510/src/share/classes/java/lang/ref/Reference.java#l-117)…